# Собрать проект под Windows Vista

Tags: c++, qt

Возможно ли с помощью современных средств сделать билд проекта, использующего библиотеки фреймворка Qt, для Windows Vista? Необходимое условие - компилятор должен быть из серии msvc32b.

Comment: а в чем проблема? собирайте...

Comment: @Crush можно. Вот для XP - там чуточку сложнее, нужно sdk подключать. Но будьте готовы к тому, что некоторые вызовы WinAPI могут быть недоступны и придется чуточку доработать напильником.

Comment: @Sergey Tatarincev попробовал запустить на Vista собранное пустое консольное приложение - затребовало кроме библиотек Qt еще какие-то системные. Видимо, об этом пишет коллега в другом комментарии.

Comment: потому что нельзя с кютом просто скопировать бинарник. Очень часто нужны еще и  vcredist для нужной версии студии (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0)

Comment: @KoVadim да, этот redist установил на Vista. А есть ли ограничения по использованию msvc - можно использовать любой или конкретно 2015, 2017 или 2019?

Comment: @Crush - мне о таких ограничениях не известно

Comment: @KoVadim большое спасибо, буду разбираться!

Comment: бородатые программисты компилят под mingw. проще будет с кросс-компиляцией

Comment: у автора исходников условие компилить через msvc